# jQuery AJAX requests time out after first request

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, cordova

I'm writing an app using PhoneGap/jQuery that fetches JSON data from a remote server. I've made two (roughly) equivalent "getJSON" functions, one using standard JavaScript, and another that uses jQuery:

```
getJSON = function(url, callback) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", url, false);
    request.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState != 4) {
            return;
        }

        if (request.status == 200) {
            callback(JSON.parse(request.responseText));
        } else {
            alert("Error: " + request.status);
        }
    }
    request.send(null);
};
```

The standard (though probably inelegant) function appears to work fine in all cases I've tried. However, the jQuery version:

```
jqGetJSON = function(url, callback) {
    $.ajax(url, {
        cache: false,
        success: callback,
        error: function(jqxhr, message) {
            alert("AJAX error: " + message + ". Please retry.");
        }
    });
};
```

... only seems to work once. I called both like so:

```
getJSON("http://example.com/blah/json", function(data) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
}); // this works multiple times

jqGetJSON("http://example.com/blah/json", function(data) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data);
}); // this succeeds

jqGetJSON("http://example.com/blah/json", function(data) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data);
}); // this times out
```

The second call never returns, and adding a 'timeout' parameter to the jQuery options consistently calls the error function every time another request is made. There's also no console output of any kind that I've been able to find. Different jQuery requests to other URLs will work as well (e.g. separate "search" and "get info" requests), but again only once, and restarting the app fixes the problem.

I'm sure that I'm missing something obvious here, maybe someone more familiar with can offer some insight as to what it is?

Thanks in advance!

(I'm using PhoneGap 1.5 with jQuery 1.7.1, and testing on a device running Android 2.3.7)

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue with PhoneGap 1.5 (i.e. Apache Cordova 1.5), using jQuery 1.6.4.  I followed another user's suggestion to rollback to PhoneGap 1.4.1, and it solved the issue for me.  In my case, it was one particular call to getJSON (or .ajax, didn't matter which way I performed the request) - after that one failed call (which would always timeout), every subsequent call was failing.  Obviously a PhoneGap issue of some sort.  In addition to replacing the JAR file and Javascript file, when rolling back to 1.4.1, don't forget to change the plugin names back to the old com.phonegap.* names in your plugin.xml and to rename your cordova.xml to phonegap.xml (and change the cordova block name).

Good luck!